# Como criar um sistema de login seguro ligado a base de dados no laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

Tenho um projeto em laveral 5.3 que estou a construir uma administração.

Eu já tenho a estrutura da base de dados toda criada. Quero agora fazer um login com campos de `username` e `password`. Não vai ter registo público, é só login.

Eu já criei um sistema, mas não está a funcionar, pois 
indica-me que a tabela `users` não existe. Só que eu quero usar a minhas próprias tabelas e não sei como, e quero que seja um login seguro com validações.

Se me puderem ajudar.

**Rotas**

```
Route::get('admin/login', 'admin\LoginController@showLogin'); // Mostrar login
Route::post('admin/login', 'admin\LoginController@postLogin'); // Verificar datos
Route::get('admin/logout', 'admin\LoginController@logOut'); // Finalizar sesión

Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get('admin', function (){

    });
});
```

**Controller Login**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LoginController extends Controller{

    public function showLogin (){

        if (Auth::check()){
            return Redirect::to('/admin');
        }
        return view('admin/login');
    } 

    public function postLogin(){

        $data = [
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($data, Input::get('remember')))
        {

            return Redirect::intended('admin');
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', 'Invalid data')->withInput();
    }

    public function logOut(){
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('admin/login')->with('error_message', 'Logged out correctly');
    }
}
```

**Config.php**

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: O que que é Laveral ?

Comment: Embora a versão seja diferente, o processo é o mesmo.

Comment: Tive a ver mas nesta versão não esta igual como eles dizem ali para fazer

Comment: O próprio sistema de autenticação do Laravel tem suas validações. Se você mudar a tabela, não vai mudar a segurança. Se quiser validações adicionais, você pode usar o Validator do Laravel para esse fim. Eu acho que a pergunta acabou ficando um pouco ampla.

Comment: Você pode adicionar campos, fazer relacionamentos com a mesma tabela, trocá-la por outra pode significar que precise escrever código e conhecer como funciona o processo, não é fácil, mas, é possivel, só acredito ser desnecessário. Faça com a tabela atual mesmo, e com a mesma classe isso poupa tempo, as atualizações estão sempre acontecendo etc ...

Comment: @DiegoSouza acredito que não seja duplicada, pois muda bastante coisa do `Laravel 5.1` para o `5.3`

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta está bem ampla, mas pelo que entendi você deseja usar uma tabela sua para fazer a autenticação. Então vamos lá.

Vá no arquivo `app/config/auth.php` e mude as linhas:

```
'model' => 'App\User',
'table' => 'users',
```

Altere `model` para o nome da sua `model` e `table` para o nome da sua tabela no banco.

No `Laravel 5.3` vem essas linhas comentadas, tire o comentário e faça a ação, lembre que a nova tabela deve ter os campos necessários para a autenticação.

```
// 'users' => [
//     'driver' => 'database',
//     'table' => 'users',  //Aqui você coloca o nome da sua tabela
// ],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class, //Aqui você coloca sua model
],
```

Porém isso não muda a lógica de autenticação do `Laravel`, simplesmente altera a tabela e a `model`.

Comment: Mas eu ja tive nesse ficheiro e nao enho isso no codigo eu vou por acima o codigo que tenho la  para facilitar

Comment: Já pos la veja e edita a pergunta conforme devo fazer entao

Comment: Vou editar a resposta

Comment: Editei a resposta, de uma olhada por favor.

Comment: nao percebi isso da model o que e a model ? e onde sao criadas ?

Comment: @CésarSousa model vem do padrão MVC que independe da linguagem, a grosso modo podemos falar que é a classe de entidade. Nela você define os atributos da entidade, lógica de negócio, o diretório padrão das models no `Laravel` é `\app`, mas recomendo que dê uma olhada na documentação e na maneira que é feito o desenvolvimento com `Laravel`, para não mexer em coisas erradas.

Comment: Eu ja consegui alterar a tabela mas agora dame um erro quando tento fazer login a Undefined index: password

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52007/discussion-between-felipe-paetzold-and-cesar-sousa).

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o gerador de `Auth` padrão do laravel.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Automaticamente sera gerado as views de login, cadastro e "painel" (pós login), model e controller.

Você pode ter [mais detalhes acessando a documentação.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication)

Comment: Mas ele usa com as tabelas deles e as views geradas eu ja tenho as views que e um template eu quero usar a minhas tabelas com os meus campos que criei

Comment: @CésarSousa você pode usar o gerador e colocar as colunas que quiser, e modificar as views do jeito que pretender.

Comment: @CésarSousa mas sua dúvida é quanto ao sistema de autenticação do `Laravel` ou simplesmente como mudar os formulários de login das views?

Comment: E no sistema de autenticação ele esta a ir a uma tabela users quando nao existe na minha base de dados eu quero usar as minhas tabelas personalizadas e isso que eu nao sei fazer

Comment: Certo, vou formular uma resposta